# I've answered with R code. Shall I add the r tag to the question?

Tags: discussion, r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Syntax highlighting with r tag](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/693/syntax-highlighting-with-r-tag)

I've answered a question and included an example with R code. Shall I add the r tag to the question?

Comment: This previous question on meta has an answer relevant to your question. http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/693/syntax-highlighting-with-r-tag/695#695