# When could a "tag" become a "stack exchange community"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, on-topic, r

Initially, I will give you an example to understand my question: e.g., the tag `r` has many questions in the "Cross Validated" community, then sometimes new users ask questions with content about a bug in R, or something about R packages, and we know that questions with this content are being closed frequently, as was discussed in this question [Should most R tags be replaced with package tags?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1527/should-most-r-tags-be-replaced-with-package-tags).

So when a tag has many questions that are considered off-topic by the Cross-Validated community, is that a reason to consider creating a new site, & how would we go about it?

Comment: I am really struggling to understand what you mean by your last sentence (`So, when a tag that have a many question which fleeing of the community focus can be another community?`). Can you please try to formulate it a bit differently? Right now it is very difficult to understand.

Comment: I think "fleeing of the community focus" is an over-literal rendering of "fogem do foco da communidade" - not clear English, as @amoeba says - so I've edited your question. Please edit again if that's not what you meant.

Comment: If not [duplicate](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2542/new-proposal-at-area51-r-statistical-computing), at least related.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) is the Stack Exchange site for proposing new Stack Exchange sites. If your idea for a new site comes from observing commonalities among off-topic questions on Cross Validated, it'd be sensible to discuss it first here on CV's Meta & to link to your proposal if you decide to make one.

Your example—questions involving R—has been much discussed. As @AndreSilva points out, there was a proposal for an R Stack Exchange site, but it didn't go anywhere. Currently we welcome questions that arise from using R, or other statistical software, on Cross Validated when they're *statistical* questions. (Understand "statistical" here in a broad sense—encompassing machine learning, data visualization, &c.) The majority that aren't are programming questions, & have a home on Stack Overflow, as @NormalHuman points out. A minority are better suited to other Stack Exchange sites (see e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/r). Some fall into a grey area where it's not clear, perhaps not even to the person who asked it; many of us try to encourage & facilitate the asking & answering of questions in a software-agnostic fashion. We also maintain a collection of links: [Internet Support for Statistics Software](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/internet-support-for-statistics-software).